# Differences in OData between two systems (7.51 and 7.52)

Tags: sapui5, cds

I create some application in Fiori on 7.51 version system. After transporting a ready solution to another system with NW 7.52, there I got different OData like version lower. I mean that some entity sets inside disappears. I don't know where can be a problem, because all files are activated and are visible in the system.

EDIT: OData is auto-generated from CDS by `@OData.publish: true`.

Maybe someone had this problem?

**7.51**:

[image]

**7.52**:

[image]

**Side to side**:

[image]

Comment: seems like the transport went wrong, which tool did you use to transport? CTS or some other?

Comment: STMS, all clear. All objects are in the second system. The same way was transferred to another system with NW 7.51 and works properly. Another system with 7.53 - the same error. So basically it was not working on a version higher than 7.52

Comment: so give the code of your CDS and OData service, it may have incompatible elements. W/o the code this has no sense

Comment: for example which incompatible elements You mean? It is possible that all works in one system, and in another only partially? oData is generated from oData by @OData.publish: true

Comment: EDIT: oData is auto-generated from CDS by @OData.publish: true